# css layout - second blank page when printing

Tags: css, printing

im using the css file from this location:

http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

but somehow, when i print my page, the first page is perfect, but it starts to print a second page which is blank.

Ofcourse i only need the first page, but i cannot find why it prints a second blank page. 
Did someone encounter this before, or know what i should change?

I think somehow the css file has some properties in it, which makes my page maybe just a bit too big.

Comment: i just tried it in chrome. it only wants to print one page.

Comment: thanks for trying it. i'm using firefox, and it is to print this page which is opened by javascript in a popup: http://pastebin.com/ap2wUC6t . The popup was given a height of 1200px but even changing that is just for the popup window, and does not matter for the content when printing.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem just now and found user2624602 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846346/how-to-avoid-extra-blank-page-at-end-while-printing/19529877#19529877) hepful.

In the css just add:

```
@media print { html, body { height: 99%; } }
```

Comment: (Addition) If you say your body and/or html has a height and you than add padding och margin to it, it vill get higher and thereby create and extra blank page.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it very depends on the browser: with firefox it's quite independent from the pc you're using, while with chrome it depends both on your pc and the currenct page-zoom.

For example here I don't see any problem (both ff and chrome).

Anyway, you can try playing with [this css2 property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp): `page-break-after:avoid;`.

Comment: i just tried it with the page-break-after set to avoid, but still i get a new blank page?

Answer (score 0):

In the php code you provided you have an error in the end.

```
</table>

</body></div>
<div id="footer">
<p><img src="images/voet.png" alt="Kop" class="voet"/></p>

</div>

</div>
</html>
```

Should probably be something like:

```
          </table>

        </div>
        <div id="footer">
          <p><img src="images/voet.png" alt="Kop" class="voet"/></p>       
        </div>

      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Additionally, you are opening an body tag on line 19, inside the <head></head>. Between the head and body you have some divs. They should be within the body element. I am not sure wheather this is the problem for printing but try to fix these issues first to see if it helps before trying to fix it with css.

Comment: thanks, i just corrected this. still a blank page. looks like the page-break-after:avoid; is not working?

Comment: The page-break-after: avoid; will not help if you actually do have some white space content that the browser tries to print. It would be helpfull to see the real page or if that is not possible an jsfiddle, or just the html file.

Comment: i dont think it is possible, since the content of that php page comes from mysql. i can make a screenshot how it looks, but i guess that won't help? this is the pastebin of my code now: http://pastebin.com/pAjVPrkz

Comment: I see. Can you take view source in your browser so we just get the html and copy it to pastebin?

Comment: Ok, the td element must be closed with /td.

Comment: which td are you reffering to?

Comment: When indented the code looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/mGALjFjm and you can see that there are a lot of open tds in the end.

Comment: ook, i have changed all <td> tages to <td /> so they are closed, but it doesn't seem to matter for the print problem. it still prints a second blank page (with only the header and footer, like url, date etc.)

Comment: The td element can not be self-closed. The correct syntax is `<td>Cell content</td>`. This might not be the source of the problem but without correct html syntax it is useless to try to find the problem in the css since different browser will interpret the incorrect syntax in different ways.