# two extra blank page add when printing

Tags: html, css, printing

I am using using a CSS property for printing,
 two extra page always added in my print. for this I tried these thing:-

```
.print:last-child {
 page-break-after: auto;
 }
```

but this is not working

I am also tried:-

```
     html, body { 
     height: auto; 
    }
```

but problem is still there.

and when I using this:-

```
    .print{
    page-break-after: always
   }
```

It prints an extra blank page before

Comment: One of the things you can do to help debug this, is print pdf's. That way you don't waste ink and paper.

Answer (score 0):

please `add page-break-after: avoid` or `page-break-before: avoid` and you can reduce element spacing it also affect. if you give me url/js fiddle link it will be easier to fix issue. i have also hanged many times on print version

Comment: i have checked on chrome and firefox there is no blank page

Comment: but i checked different different machine , chrome and firefox, at the end of pages there is two extra blank pages

Comment: please have a look once 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846346/how-to-avoid-extra-blank-page-at-end-while-printing

Comment: yes, I tried all those thing ,but problem is still  :(