# CSS - set the end of the current page in printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Follwing similer quesions like [How to deal with page breaks when printing a large HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846346/how-to-avoid-extra-blank-page-at-end-while-printing), I want to do the oppsite thing, is there a way using `CSS` to set the page end point.
example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .endOfThePage {  } //some css to mark as the end of current page in print mode
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>heading</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr><td>notes</td></tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 500 more rows -->

<tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
<div class = "endOfThePage"></div>
<!--some other stuff that will be printed on the next page -->

    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

So at the end when the user clicks on print(`window.print`) there will be 2 page, one the part before `endOfThePage` `div` and one with the rest of the page.

I hope that it is clear.

Comment: does this help? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vfocw4Lv/

Comment: Am I missing somthing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I used

```
@media print {
    footer {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vfocw4Lv/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Create an extra stylesheet *print.css* and include it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

In this stylesheet define it with `posititon:absolute` and the margin in px.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vfocw4Lv/ - can you edit this fiddle to explain your answer?