# How to avoid a blank page while scaling down a page for printing purpose?

Tags: html, css, printing, scale

I try to scale down my page by using

```
@media print {
    body {
        transform: scale(.5);
        transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
}
```

That works fine for me but I get a blank page if I print it. How can I avoid this? Or is there a better way to do the job? Thank you in advance!

For the sake of completeness, an small example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      @media print {
         body {
            transform: scale(.5);
            transform-origin: 0 0;
         }
   </style>
   <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I have to mention that I have no influence on the `body`-content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to avoid extra blank page at end while printing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846346/how-to-avoid-extra-blank-page-at-end-while-printing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing `transform` to `zoom`.

Comment: That is not working. Zoom is not commonly supported, plus it is distorting everything.