# How to avoid blank pages in print in Javascript/angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application using angularjs. I have implemented PRINT functionality and when i do control p i am supposed to get one page but i am getting extra blank pages. 
Below is my html.

```
       <div style="width: 100%;" id="printThis" class="hiddenVal">
       <div class="modifyMe"></div>
       <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo" alt="Raya Financing Co.">
       <table> here goes content </table>
       </div>
       </div>
```

Below is my print function

```
  myapp.factory("PrintFactory", ['$location', '$anchorScroll', '$cookieStore', function ($location, $anchorScroll, $cookieStore) {
         var print = {};
        print.doprint=function()
        {  
         printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
                var modThis = document.querySelector("#printSection .modifyMe");
                modThis.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" new"));
                window.print();
                return true;
        }
        return print;
         function printElement(elem) {
                var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
                var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
                if (!$printSection) {
                    var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
                    $printSection.id = "printSection";
                    document.body.appendChild($printSection);
                }
                $printSection.innerHTML = "";
                $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
            }
    }
    ]);
```

I have added below class in css.

```
@media hiddenVal {
     html, body {
        border: 1px solid white;
        height: 99%;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        page-break-before: avoid;
     }
}
```

adding above class doesnt help out me!

Actually My html page is very big of may be 8 pages but i am trying to print only one part out of it. So is that causing me the issues?

May i know what would be the cause for the above issue? may i get some help to fix this? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to avoid extra blank page at end while printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846346/how-to-avoid-extra-blank-page-at-end-while-printing)

Comment: Result means what should i show?

Comment: @Ramesh Rajendran i already tried with the link you provide and that doesnt helped out so i posted my question here.

Comment: Are you sure? you did this? [Remove space while printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846346/how-to-avoid-extra-blank-page-at-end-while-printing)

Comment: yes man. I tried lot of ways but no luck

Comment: Actually My html page is very big of may be 8 pages but i am trying to print only one part out of it.