# Printing HTML: Can't place DIVs on page 2

Tags: html, printing-web-page

I am building a HTML page specifically for printing. I want to place text boxes (DIVs) on the printed report exactly where the customer wants them.

Challenge:

- My HTML needs to print 2 pages.
- Each page needs to contain a box one inch from the left and one inch from the top. The box should be 1 inch wide and 1 inch high.

Sounds easy, right?

I came up with the following HTML code, but it contains a problem.
On page 2, the box is printed just a tiny bit higher than on page 1. You can spot the problem int the print preview. The problem appears in every browser I tried... so I can't even blame the browser!

Any ideas?

This is my attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        @page {
            margin: 0mm;
        }

        .box {
            position: absolute;
            left: 1in;
            top: 1in;
            width: 1in;
            height: 1in;
            background-color: gray;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        .page {
            page-break-after: always;
            position: relative;
            height: 297mm;
            width:210mm;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="page" id=page1">
    <div class="box">this box is placed properly.</div>
</div>

<div class="page" id=page2">
    <div class="box">this box is just a bit too high!</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is default margin on `body`, in my browser it is `8px` so you should change it to:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

The top position is now the same, but my browser shown an extra page at the end, you can do some trick to get rid of it:

```
.page {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

See also: [HTML default body margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/html-default-body-margin), [how to avoid extra blank page at end while printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846346/how-to-avoid-extra-blank-page-at-end-while-printing)