# How to stop thermal printer after printing data

Tags: javascript, css

I have a thermal receipt printer. I am using javascript to print a div it's printing everything correctly apart from that it keeps printing whole roll(blank) after printing data in the start. I think the problem is in the CSS but I can't figure it out. Here is what I have got so far.

```
@media print {
html, body {
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: auto !important;
    page-break-after: always !important;
    page-break-before: always !important;
 }

.paper-size {
    width: 76mm !important;
}}
```

Comment: try saving print page to a pdf file and see if breaks are working, i think the height of the page is too high and that is why it prints blank pages

Comment: At a *guess*, perhaps setting a sensible `max-height` for the paper size would limit how much paper it can waste.

Comment: Some of the solutions here might be of assistance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846346/how-to-avoid-extra-blank-page-at-end-while-printing/7847290

Comment: @MancharyManchaary pdf has only single page + 1 blank page but problem is that printer keeps rolling endlessly

Comment: i guess receipt printers page size is way smaller than the classic A4 page also try this property `page-break-after: auto;` instead of auto