# Unable to remove the extra blank page added when printing specific div

Tags: css, jsf, printing, primefaces

I am trying to print div inside dialog using PrimeFaces print component as follows:

**1- Page.xhtml**

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/WEB-INF/templateTest.xhtml">


<ui:define name="title">Test Page</ui:define>

<ui:define name="viewname">Test Page</ui:define>



<ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="form">

            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>

<p:commandButton value="Print" type="button" onclick="PF('printDialog').show();" />
<p:dialog resizable="true" dir="rtl" closeOnEscape="true" modal="true"  id="printDialog"  
               header="print" widgetVar="printDialog" width="1400" height="500" 
               position="center top" style="height: 600px;max-height: 600px;overflow: hidden;margin-top:100px;">


    <p:commandButton value="print"  type="button"  icon="ui-icon-print" style="display:block;margin-bottom: 20px;width:150px;">
              <p:printer target="printDiv" />
    </p:commandButton>             
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="printDiv"   style="direction:rtl;width:95%;margin-top:50px;">
       <h:panelGroup id="letterTitle">
            <p dir="rtl"><strong><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif"> detail <span id="peaseUponHim" style="margin-right:100px;"> detail </span> </span></span></strong></p>

            <p dir="rtl"><strong><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif"> detail </span></span></strong></p>

            <p dir="rtl"><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif">detail2 </span></span></p>

            <p dir="rtl"><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif">detail</span></span></p>

            <p dir="rtl" style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif"><span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif">greeting</span></span></span></p>

            <p dir="RTL" style="margin-left:0in; margin-right:0in; text-align:left"><strong><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif"><span style="font-family:&quot;PT Bold Heading&quot;">detail </span></span></span></strong></p>

            <p dir="RTL" style="margin-left:0in; margin-right:0in; text-align:left"><strong><span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif"><span style="font-family:&quot;PT Bold Heading&quot;">detail</span></span></span></strong></p>


       </h:panelGroup>




       <p:panelGrid style="width:800px;margin:0 auto">

          <f:facet name="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column style="font-weight: bold;" colspan="4">title</p:column>
            </p:row>
         </f:facet>

          <p:row>
            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">col1</p:column>
            <p:column  colspan="3" style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>
          </p:row>

          <p:row>
            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;width:100px;">col2</p:column>
            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>

            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;width:100px;">col3</p:column>
            <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>                               
          </p:row>

          <p:row>
            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">col4</p:column>
            <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>

            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">col5</p:column>
            <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>                                                                   
          </p:row>

          <p:row>
            <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;">col6</p:column>
            <p:column   style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>

            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">col7</p:column>
            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>


          </p:row>

          <p:row>
            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">col8</p:column>
            <p:column   style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>

            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">col9</p:column>
            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>


          </p:row>

          <p:row>                                  

            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">col10</p:column>
            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>

             <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">col11</p:column>
            <p:column   style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>


          </p:row>

       </p:panelGrid>

       <p:panelGrid style="width:800px;margin:0 auto;margin-top:50px;">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column style="font-weight: bold;" colspan="7">table2</p:column>
            </p:row>
         </f:facet>

          <p:row>

            <p:column rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">col1</p:column>
            <p:column colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;text-align:center">col2</p:column>


            <p:column rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">col3</p:column>
            <p:column rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">col4</p:column>

            <p:column rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">col5</p:column>
            <p:column rowspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;">col6</p:column>


          </p:row>

          <p:row>
            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;text-align:center">col1 group1</p:column>
            <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;text-align:center">col1 group2</p:column>
          </p:row>




          <p:repeat value="#{myBean.myList}" varStatus="loopVar" var="materialPrint">   
              <p:row>                                   
                    <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">#{loopVar.index+1}</p:column>
                    <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;">#{materialPrint.arabicName}</p:column>
                    <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">#{materialPrint.englishName}</p:column>
                    <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;">#{materialPrint.commercialName}</p:column>
                    <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">#{materialPrint.code}</p:column>
                    <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;">#{materialPrint.code2}</p:column>
                    <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{materialPrint.quantity}">
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.#" />
                        </h:outputText>
                       (#{materialPrint.quantityWords})
                   </p:column>                                      
              </p:row>
          </p:repeat>




       </p:panelGrid>

       <p:panelGrid style="width:800px;margin:0 auto;margin-top:50px;">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column style="font-weight: bold;" colspan="2">table3</p:column>
            </p:row>
         </f:facet>

          <p:row>                                   
            <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;width:250px;">col1</p:column>
            <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>                                                       
          </p:row>

          <p:row>                                   
            <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;">col2</p:column>
            <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>
          </p:row>

          <p:row>                        
            <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;">col3</p:column>
            <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>                                                       
          </p:row>

         <p:row>                                    
            <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;">col4</p:column>
            <p:column  style="font-weight: bold;"></p:column>                                                           
          </p:row>

       </p:panelGrid>

       <p dir="rtl"><span style="font-size:16px"><span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif">notes here </span></span></p>
    </h:panelGroup>                         
</p:dialog>                         

</div>
</div>
</div>
</h:form>   
</ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

**2- templateTest.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        </f:facet>
        <title><ui:insert name="title">PrimeFaces California</ui:insert></title>
        <h:outputScript name="js/nanoscroller-rtl.js" library="california-layout" />
        <h:outputScript name="js/layout.js" library="california-layout" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/layout-blue.css" library="california-layout" />
        <ui:insert name="head"/>
    </h:head>

    <h:body styleClass="main-body">

        <div class="layout-wrapper #{guestPreferences.menuLayout == 'overlay' ? 'layout-wrapper-overlay-sidebar': null}">

            <div class="layout-main">
                <div class="route-bar">
                    <div class="route-bar-breadcrumb">
                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>/ </span>
                        <ui:insert name="viewname" />
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="layout-main-content">
                    <ui:insert name="content"/>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

I am using **primefaces California theme** and it's css is here :

https://www.primefaces.org/california/javax.faces.resource/css/layout-blue.css.xhtml?ln=california-layout

My issue is that I get an extra blank page when printing. I tried all the solutions in the following link with no luck: [how to avoid extra blank page at end while printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846346/how-to-avoid-extra-blank-page-at-end-while-printing)

**UPDATE:** i noticed that when i removed the template css file : **layout-blue.css**
the issue is gone, so there's a conflicting style there but i am not able to know which one it might be ?

Comment: Have you tried wrap the content you wish to print in p:outputPanel?

Comment: I clicked print on your generated html in Chrome, and there was no extra blank page (at least, not in the print preview).

Comment: @YvonneAburrow: but then you print the whole document/page(s), not a 'fragment' like the panelGroup here.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] (a full yet minimal page, remove all things in the page that does not 'make it work' if you remove it)

Comment: @Kukeltje, done, i updated the post, i hope that the current example is clear

Comment: So it works if you don't  use templates and ui:includes etc?

Comment: Can you set up the page somewhere with the styles and everything so we can look for the problem from there instead of each of us having to create their version of it?

Comment: @Sheedo, is there any free website to do that ?

Comment: @Kukeltje, the issue is coming from the california css file when i removed it everyting works fine, there's a conflicting style in it which i don't know, i have to figure it out by try and error

Comment: Check out CodePen https://codepen.io/

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I will ask you to set some default rules in the `@Page`, as:

```css
@media print { 
  @page  {
    size: A4 portrait landscape;
    margin: 12mm 10mm 20mm 10mm;
  }
  html, body {
    height: 99%;
  }
  body { 
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    color-adjust: exact;
    overflow: visible;
  }
 }
```

This is a sample that you can check more details in [@Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) and [@Media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media). Also, as you can see, setting your `html, body` to `height: 99%` prevent your page to generate a extra 1% vertical space that could generate a **blank-page** in the process.

Anyways, with the help of **CSS** you can also prevent **blank-page** to happen applying in your element:

```css
.big-element {
page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

You can also read more about [page-break-inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside) for more details.

I hope that I have help in your path.